# The dielectric function in the limit of large frequencies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I'm having some trouble proving the following limit.
Considering the dielectric function
$$\epsilon(q,\omega)=1-v_q\chi_{nn}(q,\omega)$$, where $v_q=\frac{4\pi e^2}{q^2}$ and the Lindhard function:
$$\chi_{nn}(q,\omega)=\frac{1}{L^d}\sum_k\frac{n_k-n_{k+q}}{\hbar(\omega+i\eta)+\epsilon_k-\epsilon_{k+q}}$$

I want to prove that in the limit where $\omega\rightarrow \infty$, that the dielectric function reduces to $\epsilon(q,\omega)=1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}$ where $\omega_p$ is a constant to be determined. So far, I managed to prove that the response function above can be separated into:
$$\chi_{nn}(q,\omega)=\frac{1}{L^d}\sum_k\frac{n_k}{\hbar\omega+\epsilon_k-\epsilon_{k+q}}+\frac{n_k}{\epsilon_k-\epsilon_{k+q}-\hbar\omega}$$ , where I neglected $i\eta$. Now, I'm aiming towards using the Taylor series $\frac{1}{1+x}=1+x+x^2$, but I can't manage to simplify my response function in order to get there. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: May help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindhard_theory

Answer (score 0):

You will first want to take a long wavelength limit $q \to 0$, so that $$n_k-n_{k-q} \approx -\vec q \cdot \frac{\partial n_k}{\partial \vec q}$$ and $$\epsilon_k-\epsilon_{k+q} \approx -\frac{\vec k \cdot \vec q}{m}$$ to linear order in $q$.

Comment: Shifting $k$ by $q/2$, this is probably correct up to second order in $q/k_F$.